# How to do OpenID Connect in Grails 5

Tags: python, flask, openid-connect, spring-security-oauth2, grails-4

I finally bow to the Internet forces and am switching my public-facing Grails application from email based registration/verification to OpenID Connect (Github/Google/Microsoft).
The app is running for eight years and was recently upgraded to Grails 5.1 and uses Spring Security.

A couple of years ago i got the Google integration working with some Oauth plugin (grails-spring-security-openid?) but that was under an older version of Grails. The latest version of the Spring-Security-Core plugin still runs fine under Grails 5 but the development of those Oauth plugins seem to have stopped a couple of years ago. Some of the plugins i have beem looking at are:

- http://grails-plugins.github.io/grails-spring-security-openid/
- https://github.com/grails-plugins/grails-spring-security-oauth2-provider
- https://www.baeldung.com/spring-security-openid-connect

My real question is ‘How to do OpenID Connect in Grails 5’ but the following points are more specific and show I have already done some work on this ;):

- Is there a Grails plugin that would give me a fighting chance to
  implement OpenID Connect in Grails 5 using Spring Security.
- Can the non-Grails org.springframework.boot.spring-boot-starter-oauth2-client plugin be used in a Grails 5 app.
- If there is no such plugin, is it possible to delegate the OpenID Connect-procedure to a different framework running on the same machine and continue with the acquired credentials in the Grails 5 app (a sort of single-signon).

Answer (score 1):

To answer my own question, i have not found acceptable Grails plugins that implement OpenID Connect in Grails 5. I am now coding OpenID Connect support for Google and Microsoft in the application without using a plugin. It is not to difficult and only requires a redirect followed by one or two REST calls. Grails-spring-security will still be used for the User model, access control and remember-me support.

Sample code can be found in https://github.com/Janvanoorschot/openidconnect.

Updated dec 2022: I added a Python/Flask project demonstrating the same functionality as the Grails project.

Comment: Hi,  wondering if you had a sample app of this integration.  I'm in the process of trying to integrate OpenID in to a Grails 5 app and would love where to start with it all.  I have a Keycloak server up but needed assistance moving from our regular spring security core login flow to using Keycloak.

Comment: @DharmeshPatel I saw you cloned the openidconnect repo. Did you find it usefull. If so could you 'up' thjis answer so other people can find it?